# How do you add text or values under factor headings in R ggplot2 facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example,

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class, nrow = 4)
```

produces plots by factor. How could I add text or values like the means and number of observations under each respective heading (2seater, compact, midsize, minivan, etc.)? I think it has something to do with labeller, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using iris as an example, since there's only 3 groups (instead of the 6 classes in mpg), as well as not getting into the quirky issue created by the "2seater" in the mpg example.

(i) create summary statistics. In this case, n number:

```
ann_text <- iris %>% 
            group_by(Species)  %>% 
            summarise(n=n())
```

(ii) create custom labels

```
sp.labels <- c(
  setosa = paste0("setosa\n(n=", ann_text[ann_text$Species=="setosa", "n"],")"),
  versicolor = paste0("versicolor\n(n=", ann_text[ann_text$Species=="versicolor", "n"],")"),
  virginica = paste0("virginica\n(n=", ann_text[ann_text$Species=="virginica", "n"],")")
  )
```

(iii) plot with custom labels:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~Species,
             labeller=labeller(
               label_wrap_gen(width=10), 
               Species=sp.labels))
```

[image]

Do refer to [construct labelling specification](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html) for further examples.

Comment: You can avoid the need for the labeller function if you include the count in the facetting column: For example: `iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)  %>% 
  mutate(lab=paste0(Species,"\n(n=",n(),")")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~lab)`